# Can I replace the Next Button while I'am typing using Phonegap?

Tags: android, ios, html, cordova

Can I replace the "Next" Button or the "Return" Button while I'am typing using Phonegap?

Because our team are trying to develop a ios application based on HTML5 and phonegap, and we want to replace the button in softkeyboard for better experience.

Comment: what do you want to show instead?

Comment: show "send" button or "done" button